# SWIFT: Tips for getting videos to download faster?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, video, firebase-storage

I have an iOS app that downloads videos from Firebase (Cloud Firestore) with a feed similar to Instagram/TikTok. However, I can't get the videos to be readily available before a user scrolls to the video. Any tips would be super helpful. How does TikTok do it? Do they save a whole bunch of videos to file in the background on load?

My current VideoDownloadManager:

1. Checks if video is already loaded in temp cache or local file,
   and if not:
2. Downloads video url (view Firebase's downloadURL)
3. Returns the video url for immediate use (before playing it still
   has some delay for buffering)
4. Stores the video url in a temp
   cache (in case user scrolls away and scrolls back)
5. Begins to write video to file and removes video from temp cache on completion

With the current set up, videos play efficiently after they are downloaded. But if a video is not downloaded yet and a user scrolls to that video, it takes too long for (#1/2) above to complete and buffer enough to play. I am already using OperationQueues and prioritizing the current video over any other background videos - but this isn't fast enough still.

TikTok videos are almost always readily available as a user scrolls. What the secret?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: hey did you end up finding a solve? im running into the same issue and wondering likewise how IG/TikTok do it are able to both load and store their videos so efficiently. as a band-aid, i compressed my videos, lowering it's quality, but don't feel like it should have to be that way in the first place...

Answer (score 2):

**I have a few tips for you:**

1- when you are loading your stream you should start preheating video URLs in a background thread.

2- try not to download complete files, and just cache or buffer a small amount of file like 1MB.

3- with .mp4 files you can play videos even if they are not downloaded completely.

4- start full download when the video starts playing based on the buffer rate or video length.

5- try to use videos with the smallest file size and bitrates. when you are creating them, try to convert them to a convenient format. my suggestion will be:

```
Video:
video bit rate -> 12.5
video size -> 960x540
conversion format -> h264

Sound:
rate -> 44100
encoding bit rate -> 96000
```

6- check if the video has a buffered range of more than 25% when you are going to start the playback.

7- don't forget to do the downloads in a temp folder and clean that folder regularly. This helps avoid huge app size, the consequence of not doing that will may lead users to delete your app!!.

For iOS developers: this is my [videoConverter](https://github.com/sajjadsarkoobi/videoconverter).
also, you can use this cache video player [GSPlayer](https://github.com/wxxsw/GSPlayer)